# Prevent logging of clear command

Tags: linux, bash, logging

Suppose the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="${HOME}/bin/test.log"
if [ -r "${log}" ]; then
   rm -f "${log}"
fi
{
   echo "Start of test"
   clear
   echo "End of test"
} 2>&1 | tee -a "${log}"
```

The contents of the generated log file look like the following:

```
Start of test
<unprintable>[H<unprintable>[2JEnd of test
```

Is there any way to avoid the extra characters resulting from issuing a clear command using this style of logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to just filter them out of the stream that goes to the log file.

```
{
   echo "Start of test"
   clear
   echo "End of test"
} 2>&1 | tee -a >(sed 's/.\[H.\[2J//' > "${log}")
```

(I'm not sure how to match a literal escape character using portable `sed` alone. Here, I just use `.` to match any character and assume that this regular expression will only match the intended sequence. One could "cheat" and use `bash` to generate a literal escape character in the `sed` command:

```
sed $'s/\e\\[H\e\\[2J//'
```

although it's not cheating too much since we're already using `bash`-specific process substitution.)

Comment: This works great, but has an odd side effect where a statement such as echo "Only in log" >> "${log}" has no effect on the log. Any solution to this?

Comment: You might have some luck with using `>>` with the `sed` command, but in general this probably won't work because you now have two separate processes (the script and `sed`) writing the the same file, and the writes are going to be arbitrarily interleaved.

Comment: I ended up using sed to clear the characters from the log each time I use the clear command, but thanks for your help.